# Access to multiple domains with RSAT?

Tags: windows, active-directory, domain, domain-controller, mmc

Using RSAT for Windows 10 on a technician computer. I know that RSAT allows access to AD admin tools in the domain the computer is a member of. But is there a way to access multiple domains via this MMC? Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

use `runas /netonly /noprofile /u:Domain\User MMC.exe` then add the appropriate snapin (directory services etc.) which will then allow you to pick a server to connect to.  A trust is not required.

Comment: If I could give you 10 updoots I would.  This just saved me so much headache trying to manage DFS with a laptop not on the domain.

Answer (score 2):

many of the RSAT tools have options to change the domain. If you don't have a trust set up then you would need to use Sysinternals runas to use a different account.

for example ADUC you can open then right click and change domain.

[image: Runas]

[image: Change domain]

Comment: Add an image to show how to do that.

Comment: @jpaugh images uploaded